# @ media Screen CSS not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added the following code to my style.css file in my wordpress theme but it doesn't work. I want the body background to change for screen widths between 768 and 1024px

CSS:

```
@media screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
{ 
    body {
        background: #fff;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might have an issues with the order of the media query in which you mentioned the styles

[**check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hDQAP/1/), change the browser width to see the the media query in action

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1500px) {
    body {
        background: #000;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
    body {
        background: #fff;
        border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
}
```

This fiddle works fine, but **if you change the order of the media queries** it wont work...try it for yourself!

CSS always selects the last style that was declared if multiple style are found for an attrib.

**for e.g :**

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background: black;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: white;
  }
}
```

for `765px` ( *since both m.q cover this width* ) color selected would be `white`

Comment: Thanks this worked. I just changed max-device-width in my code to max-width

Answer (score 19):

One of possible solutions is including

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

To `head` tag

Answer (score 4):

sometimes one may miss adding px at the end of the number

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024)
```

This will not work, so px should be added as the following

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

}
```

Comment: It works for me. Do you have any other rule making it overwriting

Comment: @user2798091 Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/hDQAP/ Is it working?

Comment: maybe you should add `!important`

Answer (score 0):

you can also make another file like: **smallScreen.css** and add it directly in your head  tag under your main stylesheet using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:768px) "href="/smallScreen.css" />
```

then you can add style in the new file as well if "*only screen and...*" doesn't work you may avoid using: *only*

Answer (score 0):

if someone is still facing issues, one minor reason could be the syntax.

make sure you provided space between {and} and (max-width:1500px} --->
wrong one ----->

```
@media only screen and(max-width:1500px){
    body{
        background-color: coral;
    }
}
```

right one ------>

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1500px){
    body{
        background-color: coral;
    }
}
```

only a **single space** could decrease your frustration level drastically.